# Can I use the auth:import and auth:export tools with the Firebase Auth Emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I would like to preload the firebase auth emulator with my test user accounts whenever it starts up, the same way I do for the Firestore emulator with its import/export options. I tried using auth:import and auth:export while my emulators were running but it connected to our actual dev firebase project, and not the emulators. Is there anyway to run auth:import and auth:export against the auth emulator?

For reference, I am referring to these commands (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) and this emulator (https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth).

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Contact Firebase support directly and file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks, I sent a feature request using that form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to do this has now been added to the firebase tools

The older answers still work and may be useful

> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.1.0
>
> Support emulators:export and import for Auth Emulator (#2955).
>
> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2955

```
firebase help auth:import
Usage: firebase auth:import [options] [dataFile]

import users into your Firebase project from a data file(.csv or .json)

Options:
  --hash-algo <hashAlgo>               specify the hash algorithm used in password for these accounts
  --hash-key <hashKey>                 specify the key used in hash algorithm
  --salt-separator <saltSeparator>     specify the salt separator which will be appended to salt when verifying password. only used by SCRYPT now.
  --rounds <rounds>                    specify how many rounds for hash calculation.
  --mem-cost <memCost>                 specify the memory cost for firebase scrypt, or cpu/memory cost for standard scrypt
  --parallelization <parallelization>  specify the parallelization for standard scrypt.
  --block-size <blockSize>             specify the block size (normally is 8) for standard scrypt.
  --dk-len <dkLen>                     specify derived key length for standard scrypt.
  --hash-input-order <hashInputOrder>  specify the order of password and salt. Possible values are SALT_FIRST and PASSWORD_FIRST. MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, HMAC_MD5, HMAC_SHA1, HMAC_SHA256, HMAC_SHA512 support this flag.
  -h, --help                           output usage information
```

Comment: How do you actually implement auth imports into emulator now that the functionality exists? I cannot seem to find any clear docs/examples.


For instance, currently to import Firestore DB I have a previous DB export I pull in using: `firebase emulators:start --import=./backups/$DB_ENV/db`


What would I add to this to pull in for example an auth export stored in file: `auth.json` also?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself yet but I've now added the command help above

Comment: Thanks Sean. To solve my particular auth import issue I ended up running `firebase emulators:export ./backups/emulator` This produces the new updated metadata file and folder structure which emulator is looking for during imports—this includes an `auth_export` folder if you're on the latest version. So now I simply mirror that file/folder structure and can migrate live data into emulator. Happy days!

Comment: @shaone your comment helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @shaone did you ever find solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to get this done is to pass in the `--export-on-exit` when you run the emulator, for example: `firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit .firebase-emulators`, which will get all your test data dumped into the specified directory on exiting the emulator.

You can then just check that into your source code if you want (make sure there's no sensitive data in your emulator), and do `firebase emulators:start --import .firebase-emulators` to read it every time you start.

Answer (score 3):

Since firebase confirmed this is not supported I used a cloud function instead to do this. I first exported the users I would want to be loaded on startup into a json format, then I run this cloud function everytime I restart the emulators:

```
exports.populateAuthUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  try {
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    const users = [
      { uid: "user1", email: "user1@test.com", password: "password" },
      // put all test users you want populated here
    ];

    const results = [];
    for (let user of users) {
      const result = await admin.auth().createUser(user);
      results.push(result);
    }

    return res.status(200).send(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ', error);
    return res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

It only takes a couple seconds to run even with a few hundred users. Just make sure to never deploy this to any actual firebase environments! For local use only.

Comment: How do you execute this?

Comment: I would recommend using the built in tooling provided with the auth emulator now, as mentioned by Sean Burlington. If you still prefer to use the cloud function then you execute it by running a normal GET request against your cloud function. I generally just ctrl+click on the url for this cloud function posted in my terminal whenever my emulators start up. All cloud function urls should be listed when you start up your emulators.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @alex-egli this was very helpful

Here's my version which is based on yours with 3 small changes

1. avoid an eslint warning  https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop
   (I don't think your code is bad here and the warning could be muted)
2. add in a check that this is being run on the emulator
3. added user display name

```js
exports.populateAuthUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (!process.env["FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR"]) {
    return res
      .status(403)
      .send("ACCESS DENIED. This function is ONLY available via an emulator");
  }
  const users = [
    {
      uid: "user1",
      displayName: "one Local Admin",
      email: "one@test.com",
      password: "password",
    },
    {
      uid: "user2",
      displayName: "two Local Admin",
      email: "two@test.com",
      password: "password",
    },
    // put all test users you want populated here
  ];

  const results = [];
  const promises = [];
  for (let user of users) {
    let promise = admin
      .auth()
      .createUser(user)
      .then((result) => {
        return result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error.message; // continue on errors (eg duplicate users)
      });

    promises.push(promise);
  }
  await Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
    results.push(result);
    return;
  });
  res.header("Content-type", "application/json");
  return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Comment: I really like your emulator check, I'm going to add that to my local code. I intentionally add my users in serial because in my case I'm adding a few hundred users and I don't want to overload the number of available connections or local resources. If you're adding less than a hundred then doing it in parallel the way you have here is probably best.

Comment: How to execute this action? In some script or from my application code?

Comment: This example used cloud functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

But note that you can now import and export auth data via the emulators directly as https://stackoverflow.com/a/65754945/1537692

Comment: Any reason this would still be updating production? What firebase-admin version is needed to pick up emulators? All other functionality is working with updating the emulators

Answer (score -1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_standard_scrypt_hashed_passwords

```
admin
  .auth()
  .importUsers(
    [
      {
        uid: 'some-uid',
        email: 'user@example.com',
        // Must be provided in a byte buffer.
        passwordHash: Buffer.from('password-hash'),
        // Must be provided in a byte buffer.
        passwordSalt: Buffer.from('salt'),
      },
    ],
    {
      hash: {
        algorithm: 'STANDARD_SCRYPT',
        memoryCost: 1024,
        parallelization: 16,
        blockSize: 8,
        derivedKeyLength: 64,
      },
    }
  )
  .then((results) => {
    results.errors.forEach((indexedError) => {
      console.log(`Error importing user ${indexedError.index}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error importing users :', error);
  });
```